# How can I check modified date of file in nginx lua script?

Tags: nginx, lua

all

I'm creating a simple service to return content of a file. This is very straightforward except that the service should return 404 if the file is outdated. I'm thinking to use Nginx Lua script to check the file date. Unfortunately, I didn't see such API to get modified date of file in [standard IO module](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.8)

Please let me know if there is a way to do it in Nginx. Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/manual.html

Comment: Yes, I did see that. Though it's an third-party package and I'm not sure if I can use it with nginx-lua.

Comment: Can you rely on running on a specific os? If so could you use the os.execute or io.popen function to stat a file using an os specific call?

Comment: I'll try to do that with the `nginx-mod-http-perl` instead of `nginx-mod-http-lua`. Seems like perl has a built-in `File::stat`.